# Unable run basic script

Tags: ruby, require

This issue appears to be happening with every require statement I attempt to use in my ruby script.

How do I get ruby to properly use the gem?

Here is the ruby script:

```
require_relative 'oga'

handle = File.open("xml_list.xml")
document = Oga.parse_xml(handle)
print document.css("listitem").first
f.close
```

Here is the output when I run sudo ruby extract_list.rb in terminal:

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.6
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.4
/Users/sparks/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./oga (LoadError)
from /Users/sparks/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from extract_list.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I have tried running gem pristine for each of the mentioned gems and have tried running gem pristine --all. I still get the same result.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I resolve the conflicts mentioned in the response and get the oga gem to be included properly?

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of the problem. I had an old rvm ruby that broke when I upgraded to Yosemite. I had to sudo rvm uninstall all to fix the problem.

Now everything is working properly. :)